# Can XOR be used in a Merkle Tree instead of concatenation?

Tags: hash

I am trying to understand why, in a Merkle Tree, the concatanation between hashes is used - and not for example the XOR operation. Can they be considered the same for the purpose of a Merkle tree? I read what is written in this link: [Hash Function Xor](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29213/hash-function-xor) but it didn't resolve my doubts.

Comment: Can you explain why exactly the link you provided didn't resolve your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use XOR as you would not be able to distinguish the order of the values underlying the hash tree: H(H(x) ⊕ H(y)) ≡ H(H(y) ⊕ H(x)).

Furthermore you can create hashes over all zeros by inputting identical values: H(H(x) ⊕ H(x)) ≡ H(H(y) ⊕ H(y)).

So you cannot use this for a generic Merkle tree.

Comment: I think the issue in mathematical terms is that XOR is commutative and that x ^ x evaluates to the identity element (which is stronger notion than evaluating to a unique element, which is all what was needed to trip up this idea).

Comment: Suppose I have in my tree all different elements, excluding the order problem, I resolved instead commutative problem?
How could I preserve the order using only Xor in a tree with all different elements?

Comment: Possibly, but I would leave it to experts to do such tricks. It's very debatable if you would gain much performance anyway, hash trees usually compress quite a lot on each layer. If you have many small elements to hash (a few bytes each) you may be better off by aggregating the small elements in some canonical way before hashing (e.g. by using length/value encoding).

Comment: But why is so important the order in this kind of operation?

Comment: A hash tree should be seen as a method for generating a top-hash value over many parts of a single large data value, split into many blocks. If you can switch the blocks around without consequence then the Merkle tree is not a secure hash itself anymore. If this matters for your particular application is of course a different matter. That's why I mentioned a *generic* Merkle Tree in the last sentence.